# Using lseek and write lead to input lines getting appended

Tags: c, file-handling

I am trying to write into a file line by line, but I am not able to. It is getting appended in the same line. Please help.

Here is the sample code:

```
int main()
 {
     long filesize;
     char sentence[1000];
     int count = 5;
     int m_iSourceFileData;
     int i = 0;
     long offset =0;

    if ((m_iSourceFileData = open("test.txt", O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT,S_IWRITE | S_IREAD)) != -1)
     {
         while(i != count)
         {
             if ((lseek(m_iSourceFileData, offset, SEEK_SET)) != -1)
             {
                 printf("Enter a sentence: %d\n", i);
                 gets(sentence);
                 filesize = strlen(sentence);
                 write(m_iSourceFileData, sentence, filesize);
                 offset += filesize;
                 printf("Offset is %ld, filesize:%ld\n",offset,filesize);
                 i++;
             }

         }

         if(m_iSourceFileData != -1)
         {
             close(m_iSourceFileData);
             m_iSourceFileData = -1;
         }
     }
}
```

**Input**

```
$ a.out
Enter a sentence: 0
write
Offset is 5, filesize:5
Enter a sentence: 1
into
Offset is 9, filesize:4
Enter a sentence: 2
file
Offset is 13, filesize:4
Enter a sentence: 3
line after
Offset is 23, filesize:10
Enter a sentence: 4
line
Offset is 27, filesize:4
```

**Output**

```
writeintofileline afterline
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `gets`, it a dangerous function that doesn't check for boundaries,
it is also removed from C11 standard. Use `fgets` instead.

`gets` returns a string containing a line, however it doesn not save the newline
character `'\n'`.

```
write(m_iSourceFileData, sentence, filesize);
```

If `sentence` doesn't have a newline, why would you expect to find one in the
output file? `write` is oblivious of your intentions, it won't append a newline
because you want it.

You have two options:

First (not recommended): Append a newline to the string:

```
strcat(sentence, "\n");
filesize = strlen(sentence);
write(m_iSourceFileData, sentence, filesize);
```

Second (recommended): Never use `gets`, use `fgets` instead. `fgets` does save the newline (if there
is enough space in the buffer). See [`fgets`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).

```
printf("Enter a sentence: %d\n", i);
fgets(sentence, sizeof sentence, stdin);
filesize = strlen(sentence);
write(m_iSourceFileData, sentence, filesize);
```

You should always check for the return values of functions that interact with
the outside world, like `fgets`. You should always check that `fgets` doesn't
return `NULL`.

Comment: Master stroke, Pablo. Although I know it is rather an elementary question, it is very important to understand all these minute details that you have explained with clarity. Thanks again, Pablo.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
open("test.txt", O_RDWR | O_APPEND | O_CREAT,S_IWRITE | S_IREAD)
```

opens the file in append mode as the `flags` contain `O_APPEND`.

Per [the POSIX `open()` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html):

> ...
>
> Any combination of the following may be used:
>
> `O_APPEND`
>
> If set, the file offset shall be set to the end of the file prior to each write.
>
> ...

If you want to write to a specific offset in a file opened in append mode, you [can use `pwrite()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pwrite.html):

> The `pwrite()` function shall be equivalent to `write()`, except that
>   it writes into a given position and does not change the file offset
>   (regardless of whether `O_APPEND` is set). The first three arguments
>   to `pwrite()` are the same as `write()` with the addition of a fourth
>   argument `offset` for the desired position inside the file. An attempt
>   to perform a `pwrite()` on a file that is incapable of seeking shall
>   result in an error.

However, if you're running Linux, [`pwrite()` is broken](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pwrite.2.html):

> **BUGS**
>
> POSIX requires that opening a file with the `O_APPEND` flag should
>   have no effect on the location at which `pwrite()` writes data. 
>   However, on Linux, if a file is opened with `O_APPEND`, `pwrite()`
>   appends data to the end of the file, regardless of the value of
>   `offset`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. As you can see, I am using O_APPEND in my code. Like Pablo has mentioned in his comment, the incoming string doesn't have "\n" and so the strings are getting appended. I should either concatenate "\n" to the string or use fgets. Hope that will resolve my issue. Need to check that in my original application. Sample code works with the change, though.